# Minify .jsx files in React JS

Tags: reactjs, minify

How can we minify `.jsx` files which are used in React js. Normal minification process does not work.

Is there a separate tool for `.jsx` files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In-browser JSX Transformation is generally **not recommended** for usage in production.

So you have the option to precompile the JSX into plain JavaScript and then continue with the minifying like you would normally do.

For more information: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html

Personally I am using [Reactify](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify) for the JSX to JavaScript transformation and then I run UglifyJS to minify the result. It is very easy to automate in your build process.

Comment: For best results use the minifyify transform (it allows dead code elimination to exclude entire modules), and then uglify the bundle.  `NODE_ENV=production browserify -t reactify -t minifify app.js | uglifyjs -m > dist.js`

Comment: You can go for webpack with babel too.

Comment: `browserify app.js -t reactify -d -p [minifyify --map bundle.js.map --output bundle.js.map --uglify] > app.min.js` worked best for me because minifyify is used as a plugin not a transformation apparently.